# How do I change an item in a list to another item from another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, encryption, caesar-cipher

Basically I've been trying to make a Caesar Cipher type program,

```
caesar=[
"x",
"y",
"z",
"a",
"b",
"c",
"d",
"e",
"f",
"g",
"h",
"i",
"j",
"k",
"l",
"m",
"n",
"o",
"p",
"q",
"r",
"s",
"t",
"u",
"v",
"w"
]
tempword=input('What would you like to encrypt? ')
list(tempword)
checklet=0
caesarlet=caesar[checklet]
for x in range(len(tempword)):
    caeserlet=caesar[checklet]
    tempword[checklet]=caesarlet
    checklet=checklet+1
str(tempword)
print('Done encrypting, your word is: ',tempword)
```

but there always seems to be an error in this line:

```
tempword[checklet]=caesarlet
```

and heres the outputted error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Users\waisinz\Documents\python stuff\caesarcipher.py", line 35, in <module>
        tempword[checklet]=caesarlet
    TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I've already found some solutions to this on the site, but my puny brain was too smooth to understand any of them. Anybody know an easy fix, please?

Comment: the line `list(tempword)` returns a list (which you can then modify). However, your code isn't storing that list that was returned. Instead, it continues to use the string returned from `input(...)`. To fix this, change the line `list(tempword)` to `tempword = list(tempword)`. Or the previous line to `tempword = list(input(....))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the string to a list, but you are not reassigning it. You should do:

```
tempword = list(tempword)
```

There is a better way to do this using the `ord` and `chr`. Code:

```
word = input("What would you like to encrypt? ")
word = list(word)
for index, letter in enumerate(word):
    if ord(letter) - 3 < 97:
        word[index] = chr(122 + (ord(letter) - 2 - 97))
    else:
        word[index] = chr(ord(letter) - 3)
print(f"Done encrypting, your word is: {''.join(word)}")
```